# Are there alternative solutions to using mixins in styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

Is there a way to extend every styled component other than with a mixin, maybe by having middleware of some sort? For example, we are currently doing this on every component within our UI kit to handle the edge cases where we need to have a different margin than what was hard-coded:

```
const Heading = styled.span`
    margin: 0;

    ${overrideMixin};
`;

const getValues = (values, { spacing }) =>
  values.map(val => (val ? `${rem(spacing[val])}` : "0")).join(" ");

const overrideMixin = ({ margin, theme }) =>
  margin ? `margin: ${getValues(margin, theme)};` : null;

export default Heading;
```

Then we use it like this:

```
<Heading margin={['md']} />
```

The problem with this is that we have to insert this mixin into every component (and this could be around 100) - it would be good to be able to do this once somewhere (middleware).

Answer (score 0):

a route you might be able to go is to have an object of values that you can search through, while still having a default value set.

ex.

Component:

```
<Heading margin={['md']} />
```

Styled Component:

```
const marginMap = {
  sm: '4px',
  md: '8px',
  lg: '10px',
  default: '0',
}
const Heading = styled.span`
  margin: ${({ margin = 'default'}) => marginMap[margin]};
`;
```

You might have an issue with the component property `margin` being the same name as the css `margin` property

Comment: Sorry, meant you can use it like this:
`<Heading margin={'md'} />`

Answer (score 0):

Why not include all of your mixins in one file and pass it down with the theme provider?

```
import mixins from './mixins'
const theme = {mixins, vars, otherStuff}
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <App/>
</ThemeProvider>
```